# Public void method is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to access a method from another script, but I am getting the protection level error.

Even though I made the method **Public**.

This is the method I want to access:

```
public void Shoot()
        {
            timer = 0f;
            gunAudio.Play ();
            gunLight.enabled = true;
            faceLight.enabled = true;

            gunParticles.Stop ();
            gunParticles.Play ();

            gunLine.enabled = true;
            gunLine.SetPosition (0, transform.position);

            shootRay.origin = transform.position;
            shootRay.direction = transform.forward;

            if(Physics.Raycast (shootRay, out shootHit, range, shootableMask))
            {
                EnemyHealth enemyHealth = shootHit.collider.GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();

                if(enemyHealth != null)
                {
                    enemyHealth.TakeDamage (damagePerShot, shootHit.point);
                }

                gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootHit.point);
            }

            else
            {

                gunLine.SetPosition (1, shootRay.origin + shootRay.direction * range);
            }
       }
```

And I am trying to access it from another script with this line of code:

```
if (hit.transform.name == "MyObjectName" )
      GameObject.Find("Gun").GetComponent<PlayerShooting>().Shoot();
```

How can I make this work ?

Comment: To access it from other scripts, you need to make it static.

Comment: I tried to make it static, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ it doesn't need to be static because he's accessing an instance of `PlayerShooting`

Comment: @AustinWBryan Yes you are right. I read the question in a hurry. I just missed the last part of the code in which he accesses the method.

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ, yes that tripped me up to at first, I had to think about it. I just built a test of this code and its working fine for me.

Comment: Monodevelop and/or Unity may need to be cleaned. I would suggest closing it all down and reopening it. Unity throws errors sometimes for no reason. I had one before lol. Restarted Unity and now it's all good. My guess may be something to do with the meta files not updating/refreshing properly.

Comment: Is the `PlayerShooting` class `public`?

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `PlayerShooting` class should be public.

Comment: If the compile-time error does not come already from `GetComponent<PlayerShooting>()`, then the type should be accessible enough. However, it could be correct that the compile-time error comes from this.

Answer (score 1):

Try reimporting PlayerShooting.cs. If nothing helps, close Unity, throw away the Library folder, then opening it again. If problem still persists you are having naming collisions, accidental duplicate class declaration or similar.